# Loading Magento child html outside of Magento

Tags: layout, magento, block

I am loading Magento blocks outside of Magento for certain parts of my site. I can do this successfully with something similar the following.

```
require_once $docRoot.'/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
...

$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$block = $layout->createBlock('Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header');
$block->setTemplate('page/html/header.phtml');
echo $block->renderView();
```

The problem is that if the block I am rending has child blocks(html) they are not included in the output. In the example above the file header.phtml contains the following call for child html that is  missing from the output.

```
...
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
...
```

Comment: Looks to me like Alan answered the question pretty well. It may not have solved the problem the way you wanted, but I suggest you mark it as correct, unless there is some error in it that I don't see.

Comment: If you want to include the header and footer of magento outside of it, say for example for third party cms/application then you can use the follow the following article:<br />
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/using-magento-header-footer-outside-of-magento/ Happy E-Commerce!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A layout object is a collection of block objects.  The blocks are organized in parent/child tree form.

Your layout has a single block.  You have not added any child blocks to it. Therefore, when your block's template tries to render a child with getChildHtml, it can't find one, and no additional output is produced.

Additionally, the topLinks block, by default, doesn't render anything.  It needs to have links added to it.  This is typically done through other layout.xml files.

Finally, it's probably better to kick off rendering with a call to

```
echo $block_header->toHtml();
```

Below is an example of how you can nest blocks correctly, as well as call their action methods, such that you'll be able to render your blocks outside of the normal dispatching procedure.  It's different from yours in that we create a new link block, add a link to it, and add it to your top level block.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$layout         = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

$block_header   = $layout->createBlock('page/html_header')->setTemplate('page/html/header.phtml');

// <block type="" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
$block_links    = $layout->createBlock('page/template_links','top.links')->setTemplate('page/template/links.phtml');
$block_header->setChild('topLinks',$block_links);

//<reference name="top.links">
//  <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
//</reference>
$block_links->addLink('My Account','foo/baz/bar/','My Account','','',10);

echo $block_header->toHtml();
```

Comment: Alan this seems to run "isolated". I created a file called test.php and ran this. Where my templates contained $this->getUrl('') it rendered it as BASE_URL . /test.php/ . Is there a way to do this via Magento's layout xml so that you don't have to manually add children?

Comment: @JaseC I don't understand what you're asking at all. Sounds like your comment would be better off as a new question.

Comment: @AlanStorm probably right. Thanks btw for all the other resources you've posted round the web on Magento. I've seen your name many times.  I was saying if we ran the above code in 'test.php' and 'page/html/header.phtml' contained `echo $this->getUrl("contactus")` it would be rendered as 'http://myshop.com/magento/test.php/contactus' instead of 'http://myshop.com/magento/contactus'.

Answer (score 2):

The link below provides a somewhat similar approach like the one Alan mentioned although this involves adding other blocks which may contain JS files and CSS. You might wanna try checking it out too:

[How to add Magento blocks, CSS and Javascript to an external site](http://mysillypointofview.richardferaro.com/2010/07/03/how-to-add-magento-blocks-css-and-javascript-to-an-external-site/)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Init Magento
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

$app = Mage::app('default');

$app->getTranslator()->init('frontend'); 

# Init User Session
session_name('frontend');
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

# Init Blocks
$linksBlock = $app->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton("page/template_links");

$checkoutLinksBlock = $app->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton("checkout/links");
$checkoutLinksBlock->setParentBlock($linksBlock);

$wishlistLinksBlock = $app->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('wishlist/links');
$wishlistLinksBlock->setParentBlock($linksBlock);

# Add Links
$linksBlock->addLink($linksBlock->__('My Account'), 'customer/account', $linksBlock->__('My Account'), true, array(), 10, 'class="first"');
$wishlistLinksBlock->addWishlistLink();
$checkoutLinksBlock->addCartLink();
$checkoutLinksBlock->addCheckoutLink();

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    $linksBlock->addLink($linksBlock->__('Log Out'), 'customer/account/logout', $linksBlock->__('Log Out'), true, array(), 100, 'class="last"');
} else {
    $linksBlock->addLink($linksBlock->__('Log In'), 'customer/account/login', $linksBlock->__('Log In'), true, array(), 100, 'class="last"');
}

echo '<div class="toplinks">'.$linksBlock->renderView().'</div>';
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation rather than just a wall of code?